# Start Service from BroadcastReceiver never call service.onStartCommand() method

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have music service that playing audio files. I start this service from my activity. I send notification with play/pause button when i click on play button from notification i send broadcast receiver and it's working. In on onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) method i call context.startService(intentService) the problem is MusicService.onStartCommand() never called.

My receiver

```
public class PlayEpisodeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(MusicService.isRunning()) {

            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MusicService.class);

            serviceIntent.putExtra(AppConstants.ACTION_TYPE, AppConstants.ACTION_PLAY);

            context.startService(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

My manifest:

```
<service
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".backgroundtasks.MusicService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                    android:name = "cc.gm.oscarradio.backgroundtasks.MusicService">
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".Receivers.PlayEpisodeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name = "cc.gm.oscarradio.ACTION_MUSIC"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code there should be a slight change I feel, you should replace the following line:

```
context.startService(intent);
```

by

```
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

Hope this helps you.